# JAVA run multiple linked classes

Tags: java, class, tcp

I need to run different linked classes in java.

• The main one : Robot.java

• The second one : Request.java

I simulate a remote (with a TCP server) which controls Request which is a TCP client.
When Request received an information from the TCP server, it is stocked in `String req`.

I need to access `req` from Robot to decode and execute the request.

Thus in the Robot's constructor I do :

```
Request r = new Request("My robot");
r.setServer()
```

*setServer() contains :*

```
try{
            socket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
            System.out.println(socket);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            out.println("NewRobot:"+getRobotName()); //Send the information that I'm creating a new robot !
            String message ;
            do {
                in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                socket.getInputStream()
                                )
                        );//get response from server
                 message = in.readLine() ;
                System.out.println(message);
                setReq(message); // Message always contains the request, so I set the request var
            }while(!message.matches("^.*STOP.*$"));
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
        }
```

The problem is when I do  `r.setServer()` Robot.java runs `while(!message.matches("^.*STOP.*$");`

So the rest of the program is executed only when Request receive `STOP`while I need to access to each received request.

To access to this request I thought I could use a Timer in Robot, so each 100ms it calls `r.getReq()` to execute it.

**What could I do to execute both classes with letting them linked as they are ?**

Thanks, Lucas ^

Comment: What you need to call is an "Orchestrator" that drives the behaviour of the classes you want, rather than call those classes directly

Comment: Thanks @Vargan I’ll look at it

Comment: Have a look at this design pattern that could be what you actually need 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern